# store.sync time out pop up failed message

Tags: extjs

```
var BtnRouteSeqSave = Ext.getCmp('BtnRouteSeqSave');
var grid = Ext.getCmp('MyGridPanelRouteSeq');
grid.setLoading(true);
BtnRouteSeqSave.on('click', function(){

        RouteSeqStore.sync({

                success: function(batch) {
                            //var button = Ext.getCmp('BtnRouteSeqRefresh');
                            //button.fireEvent('click', button); //need at here , if not too fast refresh will get the old data
                            grid.setLoading(false);
                            Ext.MessageBox.show({
                                title: "Information",
                                msg: batch.operations[0].request.scope.reader.jsonData["message"],
                                icon: Ext.MessageBox.INFO,
                                buttons: Ext.MessageBox.OK,
                                fn: function(buttonId) {
                                    if (buttonId === "ok") {
                                        //EditWin.close();
                                    }
                                }
                            });  
                },
                    failure: function(batch){
                        //var button = Ext.getCmp('BtnRouteSeqRefresh');
                        //button.fireEvent('click', button); //need at here , if not too fast refresh will get the old data
                        grid.setLoading(false);
                        RouteSeqStore.rejectChanges();
                                   Ext.MessageBox.show({
                                title: "Error",
                                msg: batch.operations[0].request.scope.reader.jsonData["message"],
                                icon: Ext.MessageBox.ERROR,
                                buttons: Ext.MessageBox.OK,
                                fn: function(buttonId) {
                                    if (buttonId === "ok") {
                                        //EditWin.close();
                                    }
                                }
                    });  

                }

            });         
})
```

this is datastore.sync with success and failure,
but when timeout i want to `grid.setLoading(false);`
how to implement this function at here? let say after 30 seconds will automatically time out and pop up message `Update Failed !` and hide the loading with `grid.setLoading(false);`

Answer (score 0):

you have to listen to the Exception delivered by the server (in your RouteSeqStore)
take look in the Documentation: 
[Ext.data.proxy.Ajax-event-exception](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.data.proxy.Ajax-event-exception)

```
Ext.define('xxx.store.xxx', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
    autoLoad: false,
    requires: [
        'xxx.model.xxx'
    ],
    model: 'xxx.model.xxx',
    proxy: {
        type: 'ajax',
        limitParam: null,
        timeout: 60000,
        url: 'bin/script.php',
        reader: {
            type: 'json',
            root: 'data',
            idProperty: 'xid'
        },
        // maybe this is what you need
        listeners: {
            exception: function (this, response, operation, eOpts) {
                // TIMEOUT DO SOMTHING
            }
        }
    }
});
```